# How do I loop through an account class

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to create a function that loops through the account and find the account based on the given account number. It will try to use the .equals to see if the values match

This is what I currently have and the logic i'm trying for

```
    public Account getAccountByNumber(int accountNumber) {
        for (Account acc : account) {
            if (acc.getAccountNumber().equals(String.valueOf(accountNumber)))
                return account;
        }
    }
```

From my understand of the for loop syntaxs 
I do not have a array for the account class

```
 (dataType var : array) {
}
```

Account is a reference to a public account class.
https://pastebin.com/8d29Duwy

Comment: What is the `account` variable?

Comment: How does the `Account` class look like and what is the `account` variable you are looping over?

Comment: Your loop is correct and will work if account is array or ArrayList like ArrayList<Account> account

Comment: I'm trying to loop through account class and find the account based off the given account number

Comment: I do not have an arrylist of the account class. Will I need to create one ?

Comment: @ImYoonah You don't need to loop through account class because one account class has only has one account number , You can only loop through list. So first create list or array or arrayList of all acounts and loop through them

Comment: @ParveshMonu Can you give me a example of what you mean?

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create array list of Account class -> Store account objects -> Loop through it

```
private static void main(String args[]){
    ArrayList<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();

    Account account1 = new Account(params1); // Constructor
    accounts.add(account1);

    Account account2 = new Account(param2); // Constructor
    accounts.add(account2);

    Account account3 = new Account(params3); // Constructor
    accounts.add(account3);

    Account account4 = new Account(params4); // Constructor
    accounts.add(account4);

}

public static Account getAccountByNumber(int accountNumber) {
    for (Account acc : accounst) {
        if (acc.getAccountNumber().equals(String.valueOf(accountNumber)))
            return account;
    }
}
```